# pagination for the list secrets for logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am using List secrets activity to get all the secrets from key vault. I am only able to get first few values as pagination is not Woking for this activity. Is there any other way I can get all the secrets values from the logic apps.Right now I am only able to do for first page values only and as per Microsoft there is limitation of maximum 25 items.

Comment: When you say the "first few", how many are we talking?

Comment: it is 25 and this is as per limitation of Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to recreate the problem in my own tenant and yes, it is indeed an issue.  There should be a paging option in the settings but there's not.

To get around this, I suggest calling the REST API's directly.  The only consideration is how you authenticate and if it were me, I'd be using a managed identity to do so.

I've mocked up a small example for you ...

[image: Flow]

The steps are ...

1. Create a variable that stores the `nextLink` property.  Initialise it with the initial URL for the first call to the REST API, it looks something like this ... `https://my-test-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets?maxresults=25&api-version=7.3` ... and is straight out of the doco ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/get-secrets/get-secrets?tabs=HTTP
2. In the HTTP call as shown, use the `Next Link` variable given that will contain the URL.  As for authentication, my suggestion is to use a managed identity.  If you're unsure how to do that, sorry but it's a whole other question.  In simple terms, go to the **Identity** tab on the LogicApp and switch on the system managed status to on.  You'll then need to assign it access in the KeyVault itself (Key Vault Secrets User or Officer will do the job).
3. Next, create an `Until` action and set the left hand side to be the `Next Link` variable with the equal to value being expression `string('')` which will check for a blank string (that's how I like to do it).
4. Finally, set the value of the `Next Link` value to the property in the response from the last call, the expression is ... `body('HTTP')?['nextLink']`

From here, you can choose what you do with the output, I'd suggest creating an array and appending all of the entries to that array so you can process it later.  I haven't taken the answer that far given I don't know the exactness of how you want to process the results.

That should get you across the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working as expected.